# SCVMM Error 10644 - Missing WAIK files in the GAC

Tags: scvmm, waik

I cannot create a new SCVMM VM from a template. The creation fails with:

> Error (10644) Virtual Machine Manager
>   cannot access the WAIK (Windows
>   Automated Installation Kit) Image
>   Manager DLLs. Recommended Action
>   Install WAIK and ensure that the Image
>   Manager DLLs are installed in the GAC
>   (Global Assembly Cache).

I was getting this error so I reinstalled on a new box and I still get there error. I have created templates from 2 different hosts to be sure that wasn't the problem. I've uninstalled and reinstalled WAIK several times. Has anyone fixed this problem? I've seen it on a couple forums and reinstalling SCVMM seemed to be the only answer...but that didn't work for me.

Comment: Did you uninstall the waik then install or did you run the waik install over the top of the existing install?

Comment: Uninstalled and reinstalled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied the files right from the WAIK installation folder for the Image Manager (C:\Program Files\Windows AIK\Tools\Image Manager by default) into the SCVMM R2 installation folder (C:\Program Files\Microsoft System Center Virtual Machine Manager 2008 R2\bin by default).

This got er' workin again.